# How to animate TextView with Alpha from Left to Right?

Tags: android, animation, textview, alpha

I'm working on Android TextView animation.

Requirement is TextView is at fix location of the screen and **every character should be animate with alpha** (Lower to higher). I've tried couple of libraries unfortunately it doesn’t work for me.

**Reference screenshot:**

[image]

If anybody has solution for this, kindly provide it. Thanks

Comment: That's gonna be insanely tricky since font rendering is driven by the system, so you would need something like drawing each individual letter separately. If your background is not complex (single color) you can instead apply a gradient of transparent -> that color on top of textview and mock the effect by animating the gradient.

Comment: Maybe you can use spannable string and object animator and in every animation loop set a span color with variable alpha. But I'm not sure how to do that exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lots of research on the same, I'm posting my own answer.

#### Steps:

1. Create **CustomTextLayout**

   ```
   class CustomTextLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
       context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
   ) : LinearLayoutCompat(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

       private var characterAnimationTime = 100
       private var textSize = 22f
       private var letterSpacing = 0f
       private var animationDuration = 2000L

       init {
           orientation = HORIZONTAL
           val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextLayout, defStyleAttr, 0)
           textSize = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomTextLayout_textSize, textSize)
           typedArray.recycle()
       }

       /**
        * This function sets the animated alpha text
        * @param context Context of Activity / Fragment
        * @param text Text string
        * @param initialDelay Start animation delay
        */
       fun setAnimatedText(context: Context, text: String, initialDelay: Long = 0) {
           var textDrawPosition = 0
           Handler().postDelayed({
               for (char in text) {
                   val textView = getTextView(char.toString())
                   textView.visibility = View.GONE
                   this.addView(textView)
                   textDrawPosition++
                   drawAnimatedText(
                       context,
                       this,
                       textView,
                       textDrawPosition,
                       text,
                       (textDrawPosition * characterAnimationTime).toLong()
                   )
               }
           }, initialDelay)
       }

       private fun drawAnimatedText(
           context: Context,
           parentView: LinearLayoutCompat,
           textView: AppCompatTextView,
           position: Int,
           text: String,
           initialDelay: Long
       ) {
           val colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluator(), Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK)
           colorAnimation.startDelay = initialDelay
           colorAnimation.duration = animationDuration
           colorAnimation.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
               override fun onAnimationStart(animator: Animator) {
                   textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
               }

               override fun onAnimationEnd(animator: Animator) {
                   if (position == text.length) {
                       val updatedTextView = getTextView(text)
                       updatedTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                       updatedTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                       parentView.removeAllViews()
                       parentView.addView(updatedTextView)
                   }
               }

               override fun onAnimationCancel(animator: Animator) {

               }

               override fun onAnimationRepeat(animator: Animator) {

               }
           })
           colorAnimation.addUpdateListener {
               textView.setTextColor(it.animatedValue as Int)
           }
           colorAnimation.start()
       }

       private fun getTextView(text: String): AppCompatTextView {
           val textView = AppCompatTextView(context)
           textView.text = text
           textView.textSize = textSize
           textView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.ITALIC)
           textView.letterSpacing = letterSpacing
           return textView
       }
   ```
2. Add in layout file

   ```
   <com.mypackagename.CustomTextLayout
                           app:textSize="30"
                           app:letterSpacing="0.1"
                           android:id="@+id/textLayoutFirst"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_weight="1">

   </com.mypackagename.CustomTextLayout>
   ```
3. Add **attrs.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="CustomTextLayout">
           <attr name="textSize" format="float"/>
           <attr name="letterSpacing" format="float"/>
       </declare-styleable>

   </resources>
   ```
4. Start animation:

   ```
   textLayoutFirst.setAnimatedText(this, "Some text here")
   ```

It's done.